# What has been AfD's take on Soros (if any)?

Tags: parties, germany, antisemitism

Interesting enough (or *deja vu*), [in Spain](https://www.tabletmag.com/jewish-news-and-politics/284204/spains-pro-israel-far-right-party)

> Echoing other European far-right parties Vox also appealed to conspiracy theories. For instance, invoking the demonized figure of the Hungarian Jewish philanthropist George Soros, whom they accuse of supporting Catalan separatism and financing irregular immigration in Spain. “There is Soros redoubling his efforts to favor the Islamization of Europe and the chaos in the continent,” wrote Vox President Abascal in a June 2018 tweet, “and President Sanchez is already at his command.”

I'm guessing Orban's [blame campaign](https://www.dw.com/en/israelis-fume-over-netanyahus-retraction-of-hungarys-anti-soros-campaign-criticism/a-39642016) on Soros is even better known.

On the other hand, on a quick search, I couldn't find any story about Germany's AfD blaming Soros for something, although the Soros-founded Open Society Foundation definitely sees the AfD [as a problem](https://www.dw.com/en/george-soros-to-target-far-right-in-eastern-germany/a-49304370), expanding its operations in Germany's east, a stronghold of the AfD nowadays. (Soros himself [has commented](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2019/feb/12/eu-soviet-union-european-elections-george-soros) on the threat that AfD presents but in Bavaria, after the AfD entered parliament there.) So, has the AfD avoided making public comments about Soros (especially the more conspiratorial kind)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Individual elected AfD representatives and local AfD groups have referenced Soros, usually accompanied with classical antisemitism stereotypes (shify, puppeteer, financier of the [great replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Replacement), in league with the devil, volkszersetzend, etc)

- The [AFD Saltzgitter shared an image displaying Soros](https://twitter.com/afdsalzgitterkv/status/961671158767726592) in league with the devil, saying that he finances illegal immigration.
- Representative Bießmann accused Soros of being [the biggest financier of mass-migration](https://www.antifainfoblatt.de/artikel/feindbild-soros) and demanded that [Soros should leave Germany](https://leute.tagesspiegel.de/marzahn-hellersdorf/macher/2018/10/16/61252/jessica-biessmann-das-postergirl-der-afd/) ("Soros raus aus Deutschland!").
- Representative Brandner called Soros a [shifty, dubious, internationalist puppeteer](https://www.dielinke-tf-s%C3%BCd.de/nc/nachrichten/aktuelles/detail/news/die-afd-im-bundestag-ein-rueckblick-auf-die-aktuelle-sitzungswoche00000/) ("zwielichtigen, dubiosen internationalistischen Strippenzieher").
- Höcke called Merkel [Soros-customer](https://www.belltower.news/afd-zwischen-pro-israel-bekundungen-und-antisemitismus-teil-2-93567/) and called Soros [volks-destroying and pervers](https://www.belltower.news/afd-zwischen-pro-israel-bekundungen-und-antisemitismus-teil-2-93567/) ("den volkszerstörerischen und als pervers zu bezeichnenden Ungeist eines George Soros").
- Hampel [referenced](https://www.belltower.news/afd-zwischen-pro-israel-bekundungen-und-antisemitismus-teil-2-93567/) Soros in his critic of the UN migration pact, which in his opinion is designed to dissolve the German Volk.
- von Storch is the chair of the ISSB, which claimed that Soros [is behind feminism and "Genderism"](https://www.belltower.news/afd-zwischen-pro-israel-bekundungen-und-antisemitismus-teil-2-93567/).

This [article](https://www.belltower.news/afd-zwischen-pro-israel-bekundungen-und-antisemitismus-teil-2-93567/) on [belltower.news](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belltower.News) - a publication of the Amadeu Antonio Stiftung. - contains more examples. It concludes:

> In Reden der AfD-Spitze wird George Soros [...] gerne als der wahre Herrscher von Deutschland beschrieben, der im Hintergrund die Fäden ziehe. Mit antisemitisch konnotierten Reden der AfD in Bezug auf Soros ließen sich ganze Bücher füllen.
>   <sub>My translation: In talks by high-level AfD representatives, Soros is often described as the real ruler of Germany who secretly pulls the strings. One can fill complete books with antisemiticly-connotated talks by the AfD which reference Soros.</sub>

Comment: Comments deleted. The topic of this question and answer is what the party AfD thinks about Soros. It is not a place to debate the vices and virtues of George Soros himself.